# Create a wrapper function safe input() which works just like function input() except that it returns None when an exception is raised

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my homework assignment:

[image: Homework Assignment]

And this is what I have so far. Sorry if I'm way off. I'm new to Python:

```
def safe_input():
    try:
        return safe_input()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return None
```

But when I test it out, instead of returning nothing, it returns `KeyboardInterrupt`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to return `input()`

```
def safe_input():
    try:
        return input()  # here
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return None
```